# SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: symfony2

Tags: symfony, deadlock

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213  Deadlock found when  trying to get lock; try restarting transaction:

Sometimes I got this error in symfony2 PDOSessionHandler.php, at this point

```
            $mergeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($mergeSql);
            $mergeStmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $mergeStmt->bindParam(':data', $data, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $mergeStmt->bindParam(':lifetime', $maxlifetime,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $mergeStmt->bindValue(':time', time(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $mergeStmt->execute();
```

can any one please answer me as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a little late but still:

First: you didnt actually ask a question.
But regarding your problem: A Deadlock occurs when two processes try to get a lock on a table and get trapped in a loop.

The easiest way to deal with this is to retry the transaction after a little while.